# C++ and Python Named Pipe - Access Denied

Tags: python, c++, pipe

I am trying to communicate between a phyton script and a c++ winrt uwp application via named pipes. I have a python server that sends a message to the c++ client. However, I am receiving an "Access Denied" error in the c++ Code and a "The pipe is getting closed" error from the phyton script.

Here are the source codes:

Phyton:

```
import win32pipe
import win32file

# Define the name of the pipe
pipe_name = r'\\.\pipe\myPipe'

try:
    # Create the named pipe
    pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
        pipe_name,
        win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
        1,  # Number of instances
        65536,  # Out buffer size
        65536,  # In buffer size
        0,  # Timeout
        None  # Security attributes
    )

    print("Waiting for connection...")

    # Wait for a client to connect
    win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, None)

    print("Client connected!")
    message = "test"
    win32file.WriteFile(pipe, message.encode('utf-8'))
    win32file.FlushFileBuffers(pipe)
    print("Sent data")
    
    # Read the data
    #data_received, _ = win32file.ReadFile(pipe)
    #print(f"Received data: {data_received.decode('utf-8')}")

finally:
    # Close the pipe
    win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe)
    win32file.CloseHandle(pipe)
```

The c++ code:

```
HANDLE hPipe;
LPTSTR lpvMessage = TEXT("Default message from client.");
TCHAR  chBuf[512];
BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE;
DWORD  cbRead, cbToWrite, cbWritten, dwMode;
LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe");

while (1)
{
    
    hPipe = CreateFile2(
        lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,              // no sharing 
        OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
        NULL);          // no template file 

    // Break if the pipe handle is valid. 

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        break;

    // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs. 

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
    {
        DWORD errorr = GetLastError();
        printf("Could not open pipe. GLE=%d\n", GetLastError());
        break;
    }

    // All pipe instances are busy, so wait for 20 seconds. 

    if (!WaitNamedPipe(lpszPipename, 20000))
    {
        printf("Could not open pipe: 20 second wait timed out.");
        break;
    }

}
```

I tried to run a python client instead of a c++ client and there, everything worked fine.

Does someone have an idea what the problem is and how I can solve it? I thought the security options with None should be fine.

Thanks a lot,

Alex

Edit: I tried to run both scripts in Admin mode but same error message ("Access Denied")
Any ideas?

Comment: On an unrelated note: If there's an error, should you really continue as if nothing happened? That's what you do when you break out of the loop. Same when you have a timeout for a busy pipe, you break out of the loop and continue your program.

Comment: Yes you are right, this was just a code for testing, the final code will catch those errors.